# How to use MVC architecture effectively

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I have confusion over the responsibilities of a View and View-controller.

I have read the [Apple's Doc on MVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html) but it does not illustrate any clear example which answers my question.

I have a Simple Database application Which pulls the data from the database and displays it using a UITableView.

My View is a Custom view. It is basically a
collection of UITableView's displayed adjacent to each other in a UIView showing data computed from the database.

My view Controller implements the delegate for each and every UITableview.

I have a Container view (UIVIew) which contains all UITableview within it
viewController :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   UIView *containerForAllview = [tableview superview];
   //container view contains list of dataset . each of which is displayed 
   //  by it's own    respective tableview

   if(tableview = atableview){
      array = containerForAllview.getDatafortable(atableview);
      

    }else if(tableview = btableview){
     array = containerForAllview.getDatafortable(btableview);
    }
    /// like this for few more tables 

    // configure cells using this array
    cell.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexpath.row].name;
}
```

I feel something is fishy about my design.

1. Does View Controller need to be aware of my entire view Hierarchy . initially I thought my ContainerView would abstract everything.
2. (whose responsibility it is to handle user events)delegate of tableviews should be implemented by containerView or my viewcontroller.
3. If my views handle events then then my UIViews need to have a reference of my data model which violates the concept of MVC architecture.
4. Is it wrong that my container view is holding array of list to feed its tableviews or I should move that logic to view controller ?

Comment: for me it sounds, as if your model is just another (database-)controller. A model would be a class, that holds one record form the database.

Comment: My model is a core data object

Comment: than your wording is quite vague.

Comment: yes I dont want to give any specific details about my model because that interface is quite well define .. I am confused about my boundaries between view and view controller

Comment: but as you wrote it, many people will suspect, that you got the model wrong

Comment: thank your for your feedback I have edited my question for more clear understanding .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view controller should be responsible for managing the entire view hierarchy under it. The views only manage events in so far as they know when they happen and whom to notify. They seldom actually do anything about it. They just notify their event delegate (which is often their owning view controller).

In general, only your viewControllers (Which are *controllers*) talk directly to your model, and tell the views what they need to know, and respond to the view's notifications about UI events.

Specific responses:

1. Yes, ViewControllers are as aware as you need them to be of the entire hierarchy they manage.
2. The viewController handles the delegate methods, not the view.
3. No, they just tell the VC that the event occurred (through delegation, not through *knowing* anything about their VC specifically except that the VC has told the view (via various mechanisms) which methods to call in which circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to modify your design to follow MVC architecture would be to make a separate data class for each table.

You could do something where `TableA` has a datasource and delegate called `TableAData` - it's a completely separate class. Then you would just need to make sure that `TableAData` declares a protocol, so that `TableA` can listen for delegate methods from `TableAData` and modify its display accordingly!

The MVC architecture is pretty simple - let another class do all the handling of data processing. Once this class processes data, notify the view controller so it can then update the user interface! This is done through delegates or notifications, among other things such as key-value observing.